# Border goes through NavigationView

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, navigationview, winui-3, winui

#### Problem

`Border` goes through `NavigationView`

See Screenshot

[image: 1]

#### Question

How can I make the `Border` not go through `NavigationView`.

#### Source Code

```xml
<Viewbox
    Stretch="Uniform"
    StretchDirection="Both"
    Width="350"
    Margin="-900,0,-220,0">
    <Border
        CornerRadius="50"
        Width="350"
        Height="700"
        Background="White">
        <RadioButton Margin="45,0,00,500">
            <TextBlock
                Margin="20,0,0,0"
                Text="Test"
                Foreground="Black">
            </TextBlock>
        </RadioButton>
    </Border>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: This is working as designed. Show the XAML for your NavigationView.

Comment: It looks your Margin left -900 cause this problem, you could remove above Margin  and use  HorizontalAlignment="Left" to repalce.

Comment: @briannarich I missed that Margin setting. Nico Zhu might be right. Try not to depend on Margins and Paddings too much and use Alignments instead. Also try my what I mentioned in my answer if don't want to hide your contents.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `PaneDisplayMode` to `Left`.

To quote from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/navigationview):

> The default PaneDisplayMode for the NavigationView is Auto, so when the window width is less than or equal to CompactModeThresholdWidth, LeftMinimal navigation is used. When the window gets wider, the VisualState overrides the default, and Top navigation is used.

The `PaneDisplayMode` is `Auto` by default and depending on the window width, it switches to `LeftMinimal` which might hide the content with the pane.